# Check if an element of the array is the same as the following

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a service that parses a pdf to text. When I have that text I have to match an array of words. Every time there is a match, it increases a counter. So far so good. The difficulty, that when parsing to text, I have no way to check which page of the pdf I am on. I have realized that in the split, every time there are two consecutive line breaks (/ n/n) it means that there is a page change.

What I would like to do is check that the page has been changed and also, apart from counting the times that a word has been found in total, say on which pages it has been.

Example

```
let data =  `resignations / resignations. adm. mancom .: berenguer llinares
appointments. adm. unique: calvo valenzuela. other concepts: change of the administrative body:
joint administrators to sole administrator. change of registered office. ptda colomer, 6

Official Gazette of the Commercial Registry
no. 182 Friday, September 18, 2020 p. 33755
cve: borme-a-2020-182-03 verifiable in
sarria). registry data. t 2257, f 100, s 8, h a 54815, i / a 4 (10.09.20) .`



let wordsToSearch = ['resignations', "administrators"]

    wordsToSearch.forEach((word) => {
// inside of here would like to have track of the page as well
        let stringArray = data.split(' ');
        let count = 0;
        let result = ""
        for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            let wordText = stringArray[i];
            if (new RegExp(word).test(wordText)) {
                count++
            }
        }
        // the expected result would word has appeared count times in the pages etc
        result += `${word} has appeared ${count} times\n`
        console.log(result)
        /*
        resignations has appeared 2 times

        administrators has appeared 1 times
        */
    })
```

if someone comes up with another way too, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the text at those double line breaks and then analyse each page individually. Here's how I would do it:

```js
let data = `resignations / Friday resignations. adm. mancom .: berenguer llinares
            appointments. adm. unique: calvo Friday valenzuela. other concepts: change of the administrative body:
            joint administrators to sole administrator. change of registered office. ptda colomer, 6, Friday

            Official Gazette of the Commercial Registry
            no. 182 Friday, September 18, 2020 p. 33755
            cve: borme-a-2020-182-03 verifiable in
            sarria). registry data. t 2257, f 100, s 8, h a 54815, i / a 4 (10.09.20) .`


function analyseText(text, wordsToFind) {
    const pages = data.split("\n\n");
    const result = {};
    for (let pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pages.length; pageIndex++) {
        analysePage({
            pageIndex,
            pageText: pages[pageIndex]
        }, wordsToFind, result);
    }
    return Object.keys(result).map(k => result[k]);
}

function analysePage(page, wordsToFind, result) {
    const {
        pageText,
        pageIndex
    } = page;
    wordsToFind.forEach(word => {
        const count = (pageText.match(new RegExp(word, 'g')) || []).length;
        if (count > 0) {
            if (!result[word]) {
                result[word] = {
                    name: word,
                    pageIndices: [],
                    count: 0
                };
            }
            result[word].pageIndices.push(pageIndex);
            result[word].count += count;
        }
    });

}

const result = analyseText(data, ['resignations', "administrators", "Friday"]);
console.log(result);
```

In this example I just print the result for each page, but you could of course build up some result object where you keep the results for each page.

Comment: wow, I'll tried it now. Thanks. How would you keep track of the page where we at?some way to keep adding to the pageresult variable the page where you find the word?

Comment: You could just use a counter and pass it to the `analysePage` function - I've edited the answer.

Comment: awesome, thank so much. One last question because I'm a newbie with JS. In each iteration in the foreach, could aggregate a final object like this one? Just to form the correct output afterwards ```let arrayPages = []
            if(count !== 0){
                arrayPages.push(pageIndex)
            }
            let objectFinal = {
                word: word,
                pagesWhereTheWordWasFound: arrayPages,
            howManyTimeswhatFound: count}```

Comment: Updated it again, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Accepted. To concatenate all the results into just one final object array? What would be most interested is the property of the pages indexes, which is an array of pages where it has been found like [1,3, 7]

Comment: The desire result would be ```{name: "Friday", pagesIndexes: [1,3], count: 4}``` for example

Comment: Fixed it, please check :)